# How to filter an array object into an separate individual array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filter

I want to filter an array object, into a separate individual variable with array?

```
// The given array

const dummy = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jane',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Jane',
  },
]

// Expected Output
// let number = [1,2]
// let name = ["John", "Jane"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to get unique values from the original arrays, otherwise `.map` is enough.

```js
const dummy = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jane',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Jane',
  },
];

const ids = [...new Set(dummy.map(x => x.id))];
const names = [...new Set(dummy.map(x => x.name))];
```

Comment: i don't want dupplicate in the names

Comment: @Wiscaksono in fact you don't have them ^^

Comment: there is two 'Jane'

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dummy = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jane',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Jane',
  },
]

let number = [];
let name = [];
number.push(dummy[0].id, dummy[1].id);
name.push(dummy[0].name, dummy[1].name);

console.log(number);
console.log(name);
```

Output:

```js
[ 1, 2 ]
[ 'John', 'Jane' ]
```

If you having a long array you can use a for-loop as well.

```js
let number = [];
let name = [];

for (let itemIndx = 0; itemIndx < dummy.length; itemIndx++) {
    if (!name.includes(dummy[itemIndx].name)) {
        number.push(dummy[itemIndx].id);
        name.push(dummy[itemIndx].name);
    }
};

console.log(number);
console.log(name);
```

Comment: how about the duplicate name?

Answer (score 0):

```
    const dummy = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jane',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Jane',
  },
]

let num = []
let names = []

dummy.forEach((element) => {
 num.push(element.id)
 if(!names.includes(element.name))
 names.push(element.name)
```

})

```
console.log(num)
console.log(names)
```

Comment: the result is [1, 2, 3] and ["John", "Jane", "Jane"], i don't want the dupplicate value on names

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reduce function for this kind of tasks. You can define an initial value for the function and then it iterates over every entry of the array. As parameter you have the return value of the previous iterations and the value of the current entry.

```
const dummy = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jane',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Jane',
  },
]

const {id, name} = dummy.reduce((prev, cur) => {
    // skip if name is already present
    if (prev.name.indexOf(cur.name) > -1) {
        return prev
    }
    return {id: [...prev.id, cur.id], name: [...prev.name, cur.name]}
}, {id: [], name: []})

console.log(id)
console.log(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const { numbers, names } = dummy.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    prev.numbers.push(curr.id)
    prev.names.push(curr.name)
    return prev
}, { numbers: [], names: [] })
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.